# What is the "multi pass" Leeloo had?

Tags: the-fifth-element

In Fifth Element Leeloo has some document that's pretty much looks like a driver license but bears a large "Multi pass" caption on it. She display it when boarding the spacecraft and introduces herself saying *Leeloo Dallas mul-ti-pass*.

What does "Multi pass" mean here?

Comment: Uh...I guess...a kind of...future passport?

Comment: @ChristianRau ... exactly.

Comment: Pronounced: *Mooolti pass*

Comment: http://www.theguardian.com/money/2013/nov/16/sci-fi-multipass-travelcard - Milla Jovovich should get the first one. (Many Mooooolteeepasss "jokes" in our near future, folks.)

Comment: It's exactly what it says, it's MULTIPLE Passes.

Answer (score 23):

It's just an identification card/credit card/money card/etc all rolled into one.

[image: Leeloo Dallas Multi-Pass]